# Mac OS X 10.10.4 web pages not loading

Tags: macos, mac, internet, browser, web

I am running Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.

When I start my Mac, everything is working, I can browse any page through any web browser, like Safari, Chrome, or Firefox.

But after some time, this stop working, and I can't open web pages through any web browser, the symptoms are following:

1. Web pages are not loaded through any web browser in Yosemite
2. Internet connection is active as I can send and receive iMessages for example
3. When I run virtual machine through Parallels, for example Windows 10, then I can without any issues browse web pages through Microsoft Edge
4. I have a router on 192.168.1.1. I can ping on 192.168.1.1 from Terminal, but I am not able on Yosemite open web administration
5. I was trying to change DNS, this does not help
6. I was trying to clear DNS cache, this does not help
7. I was trying to clear all web cache from browsers on Yosemite, this does not help

The only way I can browse web page on Yosemite again is to restart my Mac. But this can't be the solution because symptoms are back in 2-3 days.

This is clearly problem with Yosemite and I am not able to figure out what could be wrong.

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the All Messages log stream in the Console utility say when this is happening?

Comment: Look for a proxy server running on your Mac, might even be malware (but don't panic yet).  Something else could be getting fired up and intercepting port 80 (web) traffic.  Are you using PlexConnect or any other proxy server?

Comment: I'm also having the exact same issue, same symptoms as stated above. For me, disabling Javascript in Safari seems to help, but most sites require JS so it's another piece of feedback not a solution. I'm on Yosemite 10.10.3 but  I've had this issue for a number of OS versions. How do we test for an app that is intercepting port 80 traffic?